# Integrating Internationalization (i18n) with React.js in a Malaysian Web Application

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a web application using React.js for a project based in Malaysia, and I want to make it more user-friendly by adding internationalization (i18n) support. The goal is to provide content in both English and Malay languages, depending on the user's preference.

I've researched React's i18n solutions like react-i18next and react-intl, but I'm unsure about the best approach for integrating these libraries into my project, considering the specific requirements for Malaysian users.

Here are my main concerns and questions:

1. **Language Switching:** How can I implement a language switcher allowing users to toggle between English and Malay as their preferred language?
2. **Translation Files:** What is the recommended way to organize translation files, especially for Malay language translations? Should I use JSON files, separate language-specific components, or a different approach?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.